# Handling console close in MFC dialog based application

Tags: c++, mfc, console, stdout

I have written code that allocates a console and redirects the output of my MFC dialog based program to that console.  If I close the console window, it will close my program, I get a large memory leak. Is there a way to listen for the console closing and stop sending data to it? Below are the code snippets where I allocate the console and write to it. In my destructor I call `FreeConsole()`.

```
if (consoleEnabled)
{
  AllocConsole(); //Allocate the console

  FILE* pCout;

  if (freopen_s(&pCout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout) != 0)     //redirect the stdout
  {
    this->consoleEnabled = false;
  }                
}

//in another function...
if (consoleEnabled)
{
  std::cout << outputMsg << std::endl;
}
```